# Facing issue with alignment with bootstrap grid layout

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I am facing issue with bootstrap alignment. I am using bootstrap grid layout and creating rows

```
 <form>
           <div class="form-row">
                    <div class=" form-group col-md-3">
                        <label for="DDA">TypeA</label>
                        <select class="form-control ">
                            <option value="1">C</option>
                            <option value="2">D</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class=" form-group col-md-3 ">
                        <label for="inputStatus">Status</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputStatus" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Please select Status" />
                       
                    </div>
                    <div class=" form-group col-md-3">
                        <label for="reportDsply">Report Type</label><br />
                        <select class="form-control" id="reportDsply">
                           <option value="1">S</option>
                          <option value="2">F</option> 
                         </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-3 ">
                        <label class="radio-inline">
                            <input id="chckbxCol" type="checkbox" class="dropdown-item-checkbox"> Include ColumnA
                        </label>
                    </div>
                </div>
    <div class="form-row" >
            
              <div class=" form-group col-md-3" >
                  <label for="ColumnA">TypeB</label>
                  <select class="form-control " id="ColumnA">
                      <option value="1">A</option>
                      <option value="2">B</option>
                  </select>
              </div>
              <div class=" form-group col-md-3">
                  <label for="Dsply">Display</label><br />
                  <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio"  name="rptradio" checked>CompleteDetail</label>
                  <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="rptradio">Partial</label>
              </div>
              <div class=" form-group col-md-3 ">
                  <label for="Type">Type</label>
                  <select class="form-control" id="Type" width="125px">
                      <option value="4">Insert</option>
                      <option value="5">Update</option>
                  </select>
              </div>
              <div class="  col-md-1">
                  <button type="button" id="btnShow" class="btn btn-success">Show</button>
              
              </div>

              <div class=" col-md-2">
                  <div class="btn-group">
                      <button type="button" id="btnSave" class="btn btn-success"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-floppy-save"></span></button>
                     
                  </div>
              </div>
          </div>
 </form>
```

[image]

I am not sure why TypeB is getting to end of first row and misaligning as shown in above picture. Please let me know how to push it to next line under Type A dropdown so that everything will be aligned properly.

Please let me know which class to use to align properly

Comment: Just Replace `form-row` to `row`

Comment: it's looking proper in fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/k58cfjyt/